# Parse a .py file, read the AST, modify it, then write back the modified source code

Tags: python, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to programmatically edit python source code. Basically I want to read a `.py` file, generate the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and then write back the modified python source code (i.e. another `.py` file).

There are ways to parse/compile python source code using standard python modules, such as [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) or [`compiler`](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html).  However, I don't think any of them support ways to modify the source code (e.g. delete this function declaration) and then write back the modifying python source code.

UPDATE: The reason I want to do this is I'd like to write a [Mutation testing library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) for python, mostly by deleting statements / expressions, rerunning tests and seeing what breaks.

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6: The compiler package has been removed in Python 3.0.

Comment: What can't you edit the source?  Why can't you write a decorator?

Comment: Holy cow! I wanted to make a mutation tester for python using the same technique (specifically creating a nose plugin), are you planning on open sourcing it?

Comment: @Ryan Yeah I'll open source anything I create. We should keep in contact on this

Comment: Definitely, I sent you an email through Launchpad.

Comment: Are you running any genetic algorithms on your mutations? :P

Comment: [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) provides syntax sugar for manipulating ast at import time.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[Pythoscope](https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/pythoscope) does this to the test cases it automatically generates as does the [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) tool for python 2.6 (it converts python 2.x source into python 3.x source).

Both these tools uses the [lib2to3](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/lib2to3/) library which is an implementation of the python parser/compiler machinery that can preserve comments in source when it's round tripped from source -> AST -> source.

The [rope project](https://github.com/python-rope/rope) may meet your needs if you want to do more refactoring like transforms.

The [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module is your other option, and [there's an older example of how to "unparse" syntax trees back into code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/parser/unparse.py) (using the parser module). But the `ast` module is more useful when doing an AST transform on code that is then transformed into a code object.

The [redbaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) project also may be a good fit (ht Xavier Combelle)

Comment: the unparse example is still maintained, here is the updated py3k version: http://hg.python.org/cpython/log/tip/Tools/parser/unparse.py

Comment: With regard to `unparse.py` script - it may be really cumbersome to use it from another script. But, there is a package called astunparse ([on github](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse), [on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astunparse)) which is basically a properly packaged version of `unparse.py`.

Comment: Could you maybe update your answer by adding parso as the preferred option? It's very good and updated.

Comment: @Ryan. Can you please give me tools to get AST and CFG for python source code?

Comment: `lib2to3` seems to be a bit undocumented though, although http://python3porting.com/fixers.html has some notes. -- there's a problem, the API is claimed unstable, and as explained in https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html the library is not able to parse some Python 3.10 syntax and it will be removed soon.

Answer (score 63):

The builtin ast module doesn't seem to have a method to convert back to source.  However, the [codegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/codegen/1.0) module here provides a pretty printer for the ast that would enable you do do so.
eg.

```
import ast
import codegen

expr="""
def foo():
   print("hello world")
"""
p=ast.parse(expr)

p.body[0].body = [ ast.parse("return 42").body[0] ] # Replace function body with "return 42"

print(codegen.to_source(p))
```

This will print:

```
def foo():
    return 42
```

Note that you may lose the exact formatting and comments, as these are not preserved.

However, you may not need to.  If all you require is to execute the replaced AST, you can do so simply by calling compile() on the ast, and execing the resulting code object.

Comment: Just for anyone using this in the future, codegen is largely out-of-date and has a few bugs. I've fixed a couple of them; I have this as a gist on github: https://gist.github.com/791312

Comment: Notice the latest codegen is updated in 2012 which is after the above comment, so I guess codegen is updated.  @mattbasta

Comment: [astor](https://pypi.org/project/astor/) appears to be a maintained successor to codegen

Answer (score 58):

Took a while, but Python 3.9 has this:
https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#ast
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.unparse

```
ast.unparse(ast_obj)
```

> Unparse an ast.AST object and generate a string with code that would produce an equivalent ast.AST object if parsed back with ast.parse().

Comment: Beautiful! This is the best solution for contemporary Python versions.

Comment: It will mess up some code formatting. E.g. removing some blank lines or replacing double quotes with apostrophes.

Answer (score 20):

In a different answer I suggested using the `astor` package, but I have since found a more up-to-date AST un-parsing package called [`astunparse`](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse):

```
>>> import ast
>>> import astunparse
>>> print(astunparse.unparse(ast.parse('def foo(x): return 2 * x')))


def foo(x):
    return (2 * x)
```

I have tested this on Python 3.5.

Answer (score 19):

You might not need to re-generate source code.  That's a bit dangerous for me to say, of course, since you have not actually explained why you think you need to generate a .py file full of code; but:

- If you want to generate a .py file that people will actually use, maybe so that they can fill out a form and get a useful .py file to insert into their project, then you don't want to change it into an AST and back because you'll lose <strike>all formatting (think of the blank lines that make Python so readable by grouping related sets of lines together)</strike> ([ast nodes have `lineno` and `col_offset` attributes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html#ast.AST.lineno)) comments.  Instead, you'll probably want to use a templating engine (the [Django template language](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#topics-templates), for example, is designed to make templating even text files easy) to customize the .py file, or else use Rick Copeland's [MetaPython](http://code.google.com/p/metapython/) extension.
- If you are trying to make a change during compilation of a module, note that you don't have to go all the way back to text; you can just compile the AST directly instead of turning it back into a .py file.
- But in almost any and every case, you are probably trying to do something dynamic that a language like Python actually makes very easy, without writing new .py files! If you expand your question to let us know what you actually want to accomplish, new .py files will probably not be involved in the answer at all; I have seen hundreds of Python projects doing hundreds of real-world things, and not a single one of them needed to ever writer a .py file.  So, I must admit, I'm a bit of a skeptic that you've found the first good use-case. :-)

**Update:** now that you've explained what you're trying to do, I'd be tempted to just operate on the AST anyway. You will want to mutate by removing, not lines of a file (which could result in half-statements that simply die with a SyntaxError), but whole statements — and what better place to do that than in the AST?

Comment: Good overview of possible solution and likely alternatives.

Comment: Real world use case for code generation: Kid and Genshi (I believe) generate Python from XML templates for speedy rendering of dynamic pages.

Answer (score 13):

Parsing and modifying the code structure is certainly possible with the help of `ast` module and I will show it in an example in a moment. However, writing back the modified source code is not possible with `ast` module alone. There are other modules available for this job such as one [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Demo/parser/unparse.py?view=markup).

NOTE: Example below can be treated as an introductory tutorial on the usage of `ast` module but a more comprehensive guide on using `ast` module is available here at [Green Tree snakes tutorial](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tofrom.html) and [official documentation on `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

**Introduction to `ast`:**

```
>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse("print 'Hello Python!!'")
>>> exec(compile(tree, filename="<ast>", mode="exec"))
Hello Python!!
```

You can parse the python code (represented in string) by simply calling the API `ast.parse()`. This returns the handle to Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) structure. Interestingly you can compile back this structure and execute it as shown above.

Another very useful API is `ast.dump()` which dumps the whole AST in a string form. It can be used to inspect the tree structure and is very helpful in debugging. For example,

*On Python 2.7:*

```
>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse("print 'Hello Python!!'")
>>> ast.dump(tree)
"Module(body=[Print(dest=None, values=[Str(s='Hello Python!!')], nl=True)])"
```

*On Python 3.5:*

```
>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse("print ('Hello Python!!')")
>>> ast.dump(tree)
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='Hello Python!!')], keywords=[]))])"
```

Notice the difference in syntax for print statement in Python 2.7 vs. Python 3.5 and the difference in type of AST node in respective trees.

---

**How to modify code using `ast`:**

Now, let's a have a look at an example of modification of python code by `ast` module. The main tool for modifying AST structure is `ast.NodeTransformer` class. Whenever one needs to modify the AST, he/she needs to subclass from it and write Node Transformation(s) accordingly.

For our example, let's try to write a simple utility which transforms the Python 2 , print statements to Python 3 function calls.

**Print statement to Fun call converter utility:  print2to3.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
This utility converts the python (2.7) statements to Python 3 alike function calls before running the code.

USAGE:
     python print2to3.py <filename>
'''
import ast
import sys

class P2to3(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Print(self, node):
        new_node = ast.Expr(value=ast.Call(func=ast.Name(id='print', ctx=ast.Load()),
            args=node.values,
            keywords=[], starargs=None, kwargs=None))
        ast.copy_location(new_node, node)
        return new_node

def main(filename=None):
    if not filename:
        return

    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()
    data = ''.join(data)
    tree = ast.parse(data)

    print "Converting python 2 print statements to Python 3 function calls"
    print "-" * 35
    P2to3().visit(tree)
    ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
    # print ast.dump(tree)

    exec(compile(tree, filename="p23", mode="exec"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) <=1:
        print ("\nUSAGE:\n\t print2to3.py <filename>")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        main(sys.argv[1])
```

This utility can be tried on small example file, such as one below, and it should work fine.

**Test Input file : py2.py**

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def good():
    print "I am good"

main = good

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "I am in main"
    main()
```

Please note that above transformation is only for `ast` tutorial purpose and in real case scenario one will have to look at all different scenarios such as `print " x is %s" % ("Hello Python")`.

Comment: This does not show how to print, it execs?

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking at this in 2019, then you can use this [libcst](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
package. It has syntax similar to ast. This works like a charm, and preserve the code structure. It's basically helpful for the project where you have to preserve comments, whitespace, newline etc.

If you don't need to care about the preserving comments, whitespace and others, then the combination of ast and [astor](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) works well.

Answer (score 6):

I've created recently quite stable (core is really well tested) and extensible piece of code which generates code from `ast` tree: https://github.com/paluh/code-formatter .

I'm using my project as a base for a small vim plugin (which I'm using every day), so my goal is to generate really nice and readable python code.

P.S.
I've tried to extend `codegen` but it's architecture is based on `ast.NodeVisitor` interface, so formatters (`visitor_` methods) are just functions. I've found this structure quite limiting and hard to optimize (in case of long and nested expressions it's easier to keep objects tree and cache some partial results - in other way you can hit exponential complexity if you want to search for best layout). **BUT** `codegen` as every piece of mitsuhiko's work (which I've read) is very well written and concise.

Answer (score 5):

[One of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769202) recommends `codegen`, which seems to have been superceded by [`astor`](https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor). The version of [`astor` on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astor) (version 0.5 as of this writing) seems to be a little outdated as well, so you can install the development version of `astor` as follows.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor.git#egg=astor
```

Then you can use `astor.to_source` to convert a Python AST to human-readable Python source code:

```
>>> import ast
>>> import astor
>>> print(astor.to_source(ast.parse('def foo(x): return 2 * x')))
def foo(x):
    return 2 * x
```

I have tested this on Python 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately none of the answers above actually met both of these conditions

- Preserve the syntactical integrity for the surrounding source code (e.g keeping comments, other sorts of formatting for the rest of the code)
- Actually use AST (not CST).

I've recently written a small toolkit to do pure AST based refactorings, called [refactor](https://github.com/isidentical/refactor). For example if you want to replace all `placeholder`s with `42`, you can simply write a rule like this;

```py
class Replace(Rule):
    
    def match(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, ast.Name)
        assert node.id == 'placeholder'
        
        replacement = ast.Constant(42)
        return ReplacementAction(node, replacement)
```

And it will find all acceptable nodes, replace them with the new nodes and generate the final form;

```
--- test_file.py
+++ test_file.py

@@ -1,11 +1,11 @@

 def main():
-    print(placeholder * 3 + 2)
-    print(2 +               placeholder      + 3)
+    print(42 * 3 + 2)
+    print(2 +               42      + 3)
     # some commments
-    placeholder # maybe other comments
+    42 # maybe other comments
     if something:
         other_thing
-    print(placeholder)
+    print(42)
 
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar need, which wasn't solved by other answers here. So we created a library for this, [ASTTokens](https://github.com/gristlabs/asttokens), which takes an AST tree produced with the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) or [astroid](https://www.astroid.org/) modules, and marks it with the ranges of text in the original source code.

It doesn't do modifications of code directly, but that's not hard to add on top, since it does tell you the range of text you need to modify.

For example, this wraps a function call in `WRAP(...)`, preserving comments and everything else:

```
example = """
def foo(): # Test
  '''My func'''
  log("hello world")  # Print
"""

import ast, asttokens
atok = asttokens.ASTTokens(example, parse=True)

call = next(n for n in ast.walk(atok.tree) if isinstance(n, ast.Call))
start, end = atok.get_text_range(call)
print(atok.text[:start] + ('WRAP(%s)' % atok.text[start:end])  + atok.text[end:])
```

Produces:

```
def foo(): # Test
  '''My func'''
  WRAP(log("hello world"))  # Print
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A [Program Transformation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) is a tool that parses source text, builds ASTs, allows you to modify them using source-to-source transformations ("if you see this pattern, replace it by that pattern").   Such tools are ideal for doing mutation of existing source codes, which are just "if you see this pattern, replace by a pattern variant".

Of course, you need a program transformation engine that can parse the language of interest to you, and still do the pattern-directed transformations.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a system that can do that, and handles Python, and a variety of other languages.

See this [SO answer for an example of a DMS-parsed AST for Python capturing comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22118379/120163) accurately.  DMS can make changes to the AST, and regenerate valid text, including the comments.  You can ask it to prettyprint the AST, using its own formatting conventions (you can changes these), or do "fidelity printing", which uses the original line and column information to maximally preserve the original layout (some change in layout where new code is inserted is unavoidable).

To implement a "mutation" rule for Python with DMS, you could write the following:

```
rule mutate_addition(s:sum, p:product):sum->sum =
  " \s + \p " -> " \s - \p"
 if mutate_this_place(s);
```

This rule replace  "+" with "-" in a syntactically correct way; it operates on the AST and thus won't touch strings or comments that happen to look right.  The extra condition on "mutate_this_place" is to let you control how often this occurs; you don't want to mutate *every* place in the program.

You'd obviously want a bunch more rules like this that detect various code structures, and replace them by the mutated versions.   DMS is happy to apply a set of rules.  The mutated AST is then prettyprinted.

Comment: I haven't looked at this answer in 4 years.  Wow, it has been downvoted several times.  That's really stunning, since it answers OP's question directly, and even shows how to do the mutations he wants to do.   I don't suppose any of the downvoters would care to explain *why* they downvoted.

Comment: Because it promotes a very expensive, closed-source tool.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic:  So you are not objecting to any of its technical accuracy or utility?

Comment: Check the requesters edit/comments. I doubt an open-sourced library would be compatible with your proposed solution of using a closed-source tool.

Comment: @Zoran: He didn't say he had an open source library.  He said he wanted to modify Python source code (using ASTs), and the solutions he could find did not do that.    This is such a solution.   You don't think people use commercial tools on programs written in languages like Python on Java?

Comment: @Zoran: Some would call DMS expensive; it certainly isn't in the $100 category. On the other hand, it does a lot out-of-the-box that many other "free" or cheap tools simply do not.  Including parsing and transform Python reliably.  If you believe your time is free and you have a lot of it, DMS is expensive. If you need to solve a problem and can't find another answer and don't want to build it all yourself from scratch then your opinion of its cost may be considerably different.  This is the classic reason that paid-software exists vs. everything being freeware.

Comment: I'm not a down-voter, but the post reads a bit like an advertisement.  To improve the answer, you could disclose that you're affiliated with the product

Comment: @wim: The phrase "our" is long-accepted SO indication of affiliation.  There are a lot of folk that seem to down-vote because it is a commercial product, and not free for them to use.  Unfortunately for me, it wasn't free to build; I've put 20 years of my career into it.

Comment: Disclose more clearly, I meant.  It wasn't obvious to me at all until I clicked through to your profile.  I also note that the word "Our" was edited from the word "The" four years later than the original posting, so it's likely you may have collected those downvotes before your edits.

Comment: The was a long, heated argument about what it meant to disclose affiliation.  "Our" was deemed adequate, even if you don't think it enough; everybody has an opinion but they don't often know the site policies.  The "our" was added several years later, after SO decided they needed a policy for this.  Since policy, I have gone back over various answers and adjusted them; some take awhile to notice.     There was a downvote before that adjustment because I hadn't adjusted yet; now there several (3-4) more recent that that.  The NaySayers have a piling on effect.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use baron for this, but have now switched to parso because it's up to date with modern python. It works great.

I also needed this for a mutation tester. It's really quite simple to make one with parso, check out my code at https://github.com/boxed/mutmut

Answer (score 0):

I have written several utilities to do this kind of thing, and in each case my tool of choice was [`libcst`](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Instagram created this for manipulating their Python code base; e.g. to insert type annotations. Admittedly it is not using the AST, its a CST, but the structure is quite similar, and its easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

min code

```py
import ast
code="""
def foo():
   print("hello world")
"""
p=ast.parse(code)
print(ast.unparse(p))
```