# Automated way to switch from epydoc's docstring formatting to sphinx docstring formatting?

Tags: python, converters, python-sphinx, docstring, epydoc

I've got a project which I documented using epydoc. Now I'm trying to switch to sphinx. I formatted all my docstrings for epydocs, using B{}, L{} etc for bolding, linking and the like, and using @param, @return, @raise etc to explain input, output, exceptions and the likes.

So now that I'm switching to sphinx it loses all these features. Is there an automated way to convert docstrings formatted for epydocs to docstrings formatted for sphinx?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477909/replacing-python-docstrings. One wishes that user tomaz had provided some more details about his converter. Perhaps it's the same guy here: http://www.mail-archive.com/sphinx-dev@googlegroups.com/msg03159.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on Kevin Horn's answer, docstrings can be translated on the fly in an event handler triggered by the [autodoc-process-docstring](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) event.

Below is a small demonstration (try it by adding the code to **conf.py**). It replaces the `@` character in some common [Epytext fields](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/fields.html) with `:`, which is used in the corresponding [Sphinx fields](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html#info-field-lists).

```
import re

re_field = re.compile('@(param|type|rtype|return)') 

def fix_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    for i in xrange(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = re_field.sub(r':\1', lines[i])

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', fix_docstring)
```

Comment: Update: the **sphinx-epytext** extension provides basic Epytext support. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-epytext.

Comment: sphinx-epytext worked really well for me. I have shared my experience with it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775165/1465553

Answer (score 6):

[**Pyment**](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment) is a tool that can convert Python docstrings and create missing ones skeletons. It can manage **Google**, **Epydoc** (javadoc style), **Numpydoc**, **reStructuredText** (reST, Sphinx default) docstring formats.

It accepts a single file or a folder (exploring also sub-folders). For each file, it will recognize each docstring format and convert it to the desired one. At the end, a patch will be generated to apply to the file.

## To convert your project:

- **install Pyment**

Type the following (you can use a virtualenv):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dadadel/pyment.git
$ cd pyment
$ python setup.py install
```

- **convert from Epydoc to Sphinx**

You can convert your project to Sphinx format (reST), which is the default output format, by doing:

```
$ pyment /my/folder/project
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but the patches created don't include the `__doc__` string, and Epydoc markup like `B{Some bold text}` remains in the .patch files. Is that expected?

Comment: @Epu what do you mean by "don't include the __doc__ string" ? Concerning Pyment it focuses on the tags not the inlike markup. But you can open an issue to manage it.

Comment: Ah, so fields from section 2.6 of http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epytext.html would be converted, but not anything inline (from sections 3 through 3.4)?

Comment: @Epu that's it. So as I said you can request it by opening an issue on Github. And what about your `__doc__` question ?

Comment: No questions now. If module.__doc__ isn't processing inline markup, it's because the feature is not supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could write a Sphinx extension which would catch whatever event gets fired when a docstring gets read (`source_read`, maybe?) and translate the docstrings on the fly.

I say in theory because:

1. I've been meaning to write such a thing for a very long time, but haven't managed to get around to it yet.
2. Translating stuff like this is always harder than it seems.

You could also probably try just replacing all the docstrings in your code with a similar translator outside of Sphinx, perhaps using the `ast` module or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comment suggested, `sphinx-epytext` does provides the relevant support. How it worked for me:

Installing it is very easy:

```
pip install -U sphinx-epytext
```

It contains one file `process_docstring.py` that converts the epytext markups to reStructuredText markups by replacing `@` with colon `:`.

Some of the fields I found missing in there were: `ivar, var, cvar, vartype`

Simply extend the existing list **`FIELDS`** in there:

```
FIELDS.extend(['ivar', 'var', 'cvar', 'vartype'])
```

Epytext understands `@type` for variables, but sphinx understands `:vartype`.

To fix that, replace the former ones with later ones inside `process_docstring` method.

Most of the syntax or docstring parts that Sphinx can't comprehend are reported as Warnings. You can log these warnings by running `sphinx-build` with `-w <WarningLogFile>`. As per my experience with it, Sphinx is very sensitive about how a field should start or end, missing-formatting-syntax, etc.