# Swap main code language with translation

Tags: python, django, translation, swap

Now I have strings in my code and templates (all shown to user) in Polish and I have translation to English in locale's .po file (the file was generated with standard Django translation tools and then filled). **How can I swap those languages so English will be in code?** Inverting .po is easy (po2csv, swap columns in Calc, csv2po), the only problem is how to propagate the translation to code to become the main language.

Solutions that I can see:

1. write a script that will take every pair from .po and `sed` every file in my project (it won't work for blocktrans with variables inside and it requires some work)
2. change those strings by hand (hell lot of work)

Is there any faster way?

Comment: I'd say 1. would be faster, but you'll have to check everything just to make sure you didn't do anything wrong. And remember in the future to always code in English. Good luck

Comment: At last two people will check since I use "git add -p" and we do code revision. As for coding in English - I always do so. It's all about strings that will be displayed to a user, whether in code or templates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a possiblity would be to use the `ast` module to read the syntax tree your Python code, check for all the strings marked for translation, match them with the corresponding strings in your po files, modify the corresponding ast nodes and write back the modified code.    To get started, there's a nice article by Eli Bendersky on how to use the NodeVisitor class of the ast module:

- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts/

The documentation of the module itself is quite sparse, but contains some useful information too:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Also, there are some insightful questions on SO, treating similar problems:

- [Parse a .py file, read the AST, modify it, then write back the modified source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/python-parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified)
- [Can I use python ast module for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069695/can-i-use-python-ast-module-for-this)

If it's worth the effort of writing the ast parser depends of course on how many strings you have to replace: Assuming you will need 4 hours to write the script and that you are able to replace 5 strings / minute by hand, the break-even would be at about 1200 strings.

Comment: It would be quite nice solution if I didn't have the same problem with translations in .html templates.