# how to change a variable value in a python file from a python script

Tags: python

I currently have a python file with a bunch of global variables with values. I want to change these values permanently from a separate python script. I've tried setattr and such but it doesnt seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to actually modify the one script from a different one?

Comment: I wonder if the standard library has the capability to parse a Python source file in memory, change it, and then write that the a file?

Comment: Your other question is off-topic.  Please **do not mention it here**.  Please delete the reference to an "other question".  Please focus.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/python-parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is: don't. It won't be worth the trouble.

It sounds like you are trying to create a configuration file and then have your application update it. You should try using ConfigParser, a built-in module that can read and write configuration files for you with limited hassle: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: Well this is precisely what I am trying to do. I guess if there is no other way, configparser it is...

Comment: @Iango, there is another way, but it's going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

> currently have a python file with a bunch of global variables with values

Let's pretend it looks like this.  `globals.py`

```
this = 1
that = 2
```

And there's **nothing else in this file**.  Nothing.

Let's further pretend that this file is used as follows.

```
from globals import *
```

Let's further pretend that we have some simulation which needs to "update" `globals.py`

```
import os
os.rename( "globals.py", "globals.bak" )
with open( "globals.py", "w" ) as target:
    for variable in ('some', 'list', 'of', 'sensible', 'globals'):
        target.write( "{0!s} = {1!r}".format( variable, globals()[variable] )
```

Basically, you recreate Python code from your global dictionary.

This is a dreadful solution.  Please don't actually use it.

Comment: I created the relevant python files with your above code to test it and I get this error: python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    for variable in globals:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes.  You are doing something wrong.  You are typing without thinking.  Sometimes posted code has errors.  You need to think for just a second before typing to see if you understand the code.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand python well enough since I am relatively new to it? I typed your code out, was thinking through it, caught the missing parens at the end. But I thought globals (before your edit) referred to the file or maybe some built-in python variable. Anyways, thank you for your solution. I was trying out both yours and @carl's.