# Dynamically changing a variable inside a Python program

Tags: python

I want to be able to dynamically change the value of a variable of a Python program outside of the program from another Python program. I have this function:

```
def main():
    PATH = 'path/to/file'
```

Is there a way to edit this variable from another Python program? The only way I can think of is sharing a text file between the two files, one inputs into it, one extracts from it.

Comment: Have you considered RPC calls like XMLRPC?

Comment: Hmm no I haven't heard of that. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: What's your use case? There are so many ways of doing this.

Comment: A similar use case to the shared text file would be a database.

Comment: If you simply want to pass a path to some file to another program, maybe the easiest thing to do is to have the function accept that path as an argument? `def main(path='/default/path'): ...`

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to make configuration file. You can write some kind of parser for your `.py` file, search for desired string and edit it, but that's something I would not recommend you to do (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551577/how-to-change-a-variable-value-in-a-python-file-from-a-python-script)). 
For 'text file' solution take a look at [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)