# Python AST with preserved comments

Tags: python, comments, abstract-syntax-tree

I can get AST without comments using

```
import ast
module = ast.parse(open('/path/to/module.py').read())
```

Could you show an example of getting AST with preserved comments (and whitespace)?

Comment: why don't you just import the module?

Comment: That strips the comments as well. Like most parers do - there simply isn't any value in keeping them unless you're doing source-to-source transformations *and* expect the input to be written by human and the output to be human-readable. That's rare and it's quite some pain to implement, so it's rarely done.

Comment: I don't want to import the module. It can raise an exception, so I just want to analyze it. Comments may contain some valuable information, therefore I want to get them somehow. I could scan the source using line numbers from AST, but hope that there is a better way. In [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/python-parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified) guys suggest to have a look on [`lib2to3`](http://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/2to3/)

Comment: I was unaware of the difference, but if you read this question, you are probably looking for a **concrete syntax tree** instead of an *abstract syntax tree*. The [answer by @Lai Jimmy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012345/7437143) explains this, and shows you Instagram has built such a module, which gives a CST with comments with: `import libcst as cst` and `cst.parse_module(some_python_filecontent)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module doesn't include comments.  The [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module can give you comments, but doesn't provide other program structure.

Comment: The AST doesn't include them for a reason. I had some troubles with multiline strings as well since `ast.Str` has `col_offset=-1` and `lineno` is the last line of the string. All these issues can be solved by using `ast` and `tokenize` together. Thanks

Comment: Hey can you give an example on how I can parse, "#hi" using ast and token?

Answer (score 16):

An AST that keeps information about formating, comments etc. is called a Full Syntax Tree.

[redbaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is able to do this. Install with `pip install redbaron` and try the following code.

```
import redbaron

with open("/path/to/module.py", "r") as source_code:
    red = redbaron.RedBaron(source_code.read())

print (red.fst())
```

Comment: Redbaron is awesome on several ways but unfortunately it currently does not support parsing Python3.

Comment: Unfortunately, `redbaron` and the `baron` library on which it is based are woefully broken, and at least `redbaron` seems to be largely unmaintained.  I struggled to get it to do basic transformations, and in the process of fixing it discovered that the tests are not nearly complete enough.  My [PR](https://github.com/PyCQA/redbaron/pull/144) has gone 4 months without a a single response. Once I fixed that issue I then ran into basic source code parsing issues with the lower-level `baron` library.  At that point I found `lib2to3` and never looked back.

Answer (score 10):

This question naturally arises when writing any kind of Python code beautifier, pep-8 checker, etc. In such cases, you *are* doing a source-to-source transformations, you *do* expect the input to be written by human and not only want the output to be human-readable, but in addition expect it to:

1. include all comments, exactly where they appear in the original.
2. output the exact spelling of strings, including docstrings as in the original.

This is far from easy to do with the ast module. You could call it a hole in the api, but there seems to be no easy way to extend the api to do 1 and 2 easily.

Andrei's suggestion to use both ast and tokenize together is a brilliant workaround. The idea came to me also when writing a [Python to Coffeescript converter](https://github.com/edreamleo/python-to-coffeescript), but the code is far from trivial.

The `TokenSync` (ts) class starting at line 1305 in [py2cs.py](https://github.com/edreamleo/python-to-coffeescript/blob/master/py2cs.py) coordinates communication between the token-based data and the ast traversal. Given the source string s, the `TokenSync` class tokenizes s and inits internal data structures that support several interface methods:

`ts.leading_lines(node)`: Returns a list of the preceding comment and blank lines.

`ts.trailing_comment(node)`: Return a string containing the trailing comment for the node, if any.

`ts.sync_string(node)`: Return the spelling of the string at the given node.

It is straightforward, but just a bit clumsy, for the ast visitors to use these methods.  Here are some examples from the `CoffeeScriptTraverser` (cst) class in py2cs.py:

```
def do_Str(self, node):
    '''A string constant, including docstrings.'''
    if hasattr(node, 'lineno'):
        return self.sync_string(node)
```

This works provided that ast.Str nodes are visited in the order they appear in the sources.  This happens naturally in most traversals.

Here is the ast.If visitor.  It shows how to use `ts.leading_lines` and `ts.trailing_comment`:

```
def do_If(self, node):

    result = self.leading_lines(node)
    tail = self.trailing_comment(node)
    s = 'if %s:%s' % (self.visit(node.test), tail)
    result.append(self.indent(s))
    for z in node.body:
        self.level += 1
        result.append(self.visit(z))
        self.level -= 1
    if node.orelse:
        tail = self.tail_after_body(node.body, node.orelse, result)
        result.append(self.indent('else:' + tail))
        for z in node.orelse:
            self.level += 1
            result.append(self.visit(z))
            self.level -= 1
    return ''.join(result)
```

The `ts.tail_after_body` method compensates for the fact that there are no ast nodes representing 'else' clauses. It's not rocket science, but it isn't pretty:

```
def tail_after_body(self, body, aList, result):
    '''
    Return the tail of the 'else' or 'finally' statement following the given body.
    aList is the node.orelse or node.finalbody list.
    '''
    node = self.last_node(body)
    if node:
        max_n = node.lineno
        leading = self.leading_lines(aList[0])
        if leading:
            result.extend(leading)
            max_n += len(leading)
        tail = self.trailing_comment_at_lineno(max_n + 1)
    else:
        tail = '\n'
    return tail
```

Note that `cst.tail_after_body` just calls `ts.tail_after_body`.

**Summary**

The TokenSync class encapsulates most of the complexities involved in making token-oriented data available to ast traversal code. Using the TokenSync class is straightforward, but the ast visitors for all Python statements (and ast.Str) must include calls to `ts.leading_lines`, `ts.trailing_comment` and `ts.sync_string`. Furthermore, the `ts.tail_after_body` hack is needed to handle "missing" ast nodes.

In short, the code works well, but is just a bit clumsy.

@Andrei: your short answer might suggest that you know of a more elegant way. If so, I would love to see it.

Edward K. Ream

Answer (score 9):

LibCST provides a Concrete Syntax Tree for Python that looks and feels like an AST. Most of node types are the same as AST while formatting information (comment, space, comma, etc) are available.
https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST/

```
In [1]: import libcst as cst

In [2]: cst.parse_statement("fn(1, 2)  # a comment")                                                                                                                
Out[2]:
SimpleStatementLine(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=Call(
                func=Name(
                    value='fn',
                    lpar=[],
                    rpar=[],
                ),
                args=[
                    Arg(
                        value=Integer(
                            value='1',
                            lpar=[],
                            rpar=[],
                        ),
                        keyword=None,
                        equal=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
                        comma=Comma(        # <--- a comma
                            whitespace_before=SimpleWhitespace(
                                value='',
                            ),
                            whitespace_after=SimpleWhitespace(
                                value=' ',  # <--- a white space
                            ),
                        ),
                        star='',
                        whitespace_after_star=SimpleWhitespace(
                            value='',
                        ),
                        whitespace_after_arg=SimpleWhitespace(
                            value='',
                        ),
                    ),
                    Arg(
                        value=Integer(
                            value='2',
                            lpar=[],
                            rpar=[],
                        ),
                        keyword=None,
                        equal=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
                        comma=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
                        star='',
                        whitespace_after_star=SimpleWhitespace(
                            value='',
                        ),
                        whitespace_after_arg=SimpleWhitespace(
                            value='',
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
                lpar=[],
                rpar=[],
                whitespace_after_func=SimpleWhitespace(
                    value='',
                ),
                whitespace_before_args=SimpleWhitespace(
                    value='',
                ),
            ),
            semicolon=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
        ),
    ],
    leading_lines=[],
    trailing_whitespace=TrailingWhitespace(
        whitespace=SimpleWhitespace(
            value='  ',
        ),
        comment=Comment(
            value='# a comment',  # <--- comment
        ),
        newline=Newline(
            value=None,
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 8):

A few people have already mentioned [lib2to3](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/lib2to3) but I wanted to create a more complete answer, because this tool is an under-appreciated gem. Don't bother with `redbaron`.

`lib2to3` is comprised of a few parts:

- **the parser**: tokens, grammar, etc
- **fixers**: library of transformations
- **refactor tools**: applies fixers to a parsed ast
- **the command line**: choose fixes to apply and run them in parallel using multiprocessing

Below is a brief introduction to using `lib2to3` for transformations and scraping data (i.e. extraction).

### Transformations

If you'd like to transform python files (i.e. complex find/replace), the CLI provided by `lib2to3` is fully featured, and can transform files in parallel.

To use it, create a python package where each sub-module within it contains a single sub-class of [`lib2to3.fixer_base.BaseFix`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/fixer_base.py).  See [`lib2to3.fixes`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/lib2to3/fixes) for lots of examples.

Then create your executable script (replacing "myfixes" with the name of your package):

```
import sys
import lib2to3.main

def main(args=None):
    sys.exit(lib2to3.main.main("myfixes", args=args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Run `yourscript -h` to see the options.

### Scraping

If your goal is to gather data, but not transform it, then you need to do a little more work.  Here's a recipe I whipped up to use `lib2to3` for data scraping:

```
# file: basescraper.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from lib2to3.pgen2 import token
from lib2to3.pgen2.parse import ParseError
from lib2to3.pygram import python_grammar
from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool
from lib2to3 import fixer_base


def symbol_name(number):
    """
    Get a human-friendly name from a token or symbol

    Very handy for debugging.
    """
    try:
        return token.tok_name[number]
    except KeyError:
        return python_grammar.number2symbol[number]


class SimpleRefactoringTool(RefactoringTool):
    def __init__(self, scraper_classes, options=None, explicit=None):
        self.fixers = None
        self.scraper_classes = scraper_classes
        # first argument is a list of fixer paths, as strings. we override
        # get_fixers, so we don't need it.
        super(SimpleRefactoringTool, self).__init__(None, options, explicit)

    def get_fixers(self):
        """
        Override base method to get fixers from passed fixers classes instead
        of via dotted-module-paths.
        """
        self.fixers = [cls(self.options, self.fixer_log)
                       for cls in self.scraper_classes]
        return (self.fixers, [])

    def get_results(self):
        """
        Get the scraped results returned from `scraper_classes`
        """
        return {type(fixer): fixer.results for fixer in self.fixers}


class BaseScraper(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    """
    Base class for a fixer that stores results.

    lib2to3 was designed with transformation in mind, but if you just want
    to scrape results, you need a way to pass data back to the caller.
    """
    BM_compatible = True

    def __init__(self, options, log):
        self.results = []
        super(BaseScraper, self).__init__(options, log)

    def scrape(self, node, match):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def transform(self, node, match):
        result = self.scrape(node, match)
        if result is not None:
            self.results.append(result)


def scrape(code, scraper):
    """
    Simple interface when you have a single scraper class.
    """
    tool = SimpleRefactoringTool([scraper])
    tool.refactor_string(code, '<test.py>')
    return tool.get_results()[scraper]
```

And here's a simple scraper that finds the first comment after a function def:

```
# file: commentscraper.py
from basescraper import scrape, BaseScraper, ParseError

class FindComments(BaseScraper):

    PATTERN = """ 
    funcdef< 'def' name=any parameters< '(' [any] ')' >
           ['->' any] ':' suite=any+ >
    """

    def scrape(self, node, results):
        suite = results["suite"]
        name = results["name"]

        if suite[0].children[1].type == token.INDENT:
            indent_node = suite[0].children[1]
            return (str(name), indent_node.prefix.strip())
        else:
            # e.g. "def foo(...): x = 5; y = 7"
            # nothing to save
            return

# example usage:

code = '''\

@decorator
def foobar():
    # type: comment goes here
    """
    docstring
    """
    pass

'''
comments = scrape(code, FindTypeComments)
assert comments == [('foobar', '# type: comment goes here')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Naming this module lib**2to3** is really selling it way short.

Comment: Question 1: What is the purpose of the `PATTERN` variable? Is there somewhere a manual documenting the syntax used inside?

Comment: Question 2: Does it detect white spaces, or are these thrown away? E.g. can I find occurrences of `foo<whitespace>()` but not `foo()`?

Comment: `PATTERN` is an abstract attribute of `fixer_base.BaseFix`.  I've never found any documentation for it, but there are a lots of examples in the fixes module.  For more examples you can check out the fixes in the [future](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/tree/master/src/libfuturize/fixes) library.  Keywords correspond to symbols in the [python grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/Grammar.txt).  The grammar for the tree matching language used by `PATTERN` is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt)

Comment: The documentation for bowler -- which uses lib2to3 under the hood - provides a little more explanation:  https://pybowler.io/docs/api-selectors

Comment: Unfortunately: Deprecated since version 3.11, will be removed in version 3.13 https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#module-lib2to3

Answer (score 6):

If you're using python 3, you can use `bowler`, which is based on lib2to3, but provides a much nicer API and CLI for creating transformation scripts.

https://pybowler.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast-comments` specifically for the case (https://pypi.org/project/ast-comments/)

The library uses `ast` and `tokenize` from the standard library as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457047/18794028

```
>>> import ast_comments as astcom
>>> source = """
... # some comments (1)
... some_variable = 'value' # inline comments (2)
... """
>>> tree = astcom.parse(source)
>>> node = tree.body[0]
>>> node.comments
('some comments (1)', 'inline comments (2)')
>>> astcom.dump(tree)
"Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='some_variable', ctx=Store())], value=Constant(value='value', kind=None), type_comment=None, comments=('some comments (1)', 'inline comments (2)'))], type_ignores=[])"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other experts seem to think the Python AST module strips comments, so that means that route simply won't work for you.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Python front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/PythonFrontEnd.html) will parse Python and build ASTs that capture all the comments ([see this SO example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22118379/120163).  The Python front end includes a prettyprinter that can regenerate Python code (with the comments!) directly from the AST.  DMS itself provides the low-level parsing machinery, and a source-to-source transformation capability that operate on patterns written using the target language (e.g., Python) surface syntax.