# Python source code transformations

Tags: python, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - Parse a .py file, read the AST, modify it, then write back the modified source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/python-parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified)

I've done a search on this several times but every time I search for something like this I get basic I/O results. I don't want basic I/O.

I'm looking for either a library or some sort of resource I can start with on making Python code that can manipulate/add/detract from python files. Not automatically, but with prompting of some sort. It also has to be able to run other python files in-addition-to.

Essentially, I want an I/O system that can work on Python files effectively. I don't know if I'm just being stupid or if something like this exists....any help?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/python-parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified

Comment: It's a start, I guess....thanks