# Inverse of ast.parse

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

You can use `ast.parse` to turn source code into a abstract syntax tree. Is there a way to do the opposite - turn an abstract syntax tree into the source code it was generated from?

Comment: It seems that all aspects of your questions are adequately addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified-source-c?

Comment: @NPE Yeah, they seem the same.