# Source code generation

Tags: python, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, grako

I am using grako utility of python to parse my OIL file to AST. but i want to re generate the source code back from the AST after modifying the AST. Is grako is having feature to do this or else any other utility in python is available for this source code re generation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a .py file, read the AST, modify it, then write back the modified source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified-source-c)

Comment: See this SO answer for what it takes to regenerate source text from an AST: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834775/120163

Answer (score 2):

Grako-style code generation is done through in-line templates using `string.Formatter`.

Look into the `grako.codegen` and `grako.model` modules/packages, and take a look at the `examples/antlr2grako` example.

Code generation is one of the least documented parts of Grako (in the README), but it is all there.