# Python - writing to python files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-writing

Is there some more convenient way to write into python files than using read/write for any file (like txt files etc).

I mean python knows what actually is the structure of python file, so if I need to write into it, maybe there is some more convenient way to do it?

**If there is no such way** (or it is too complicated), then what would best way to normally modify python file just using normal `write` (example below)?

I have lots of these files in my subdirectories called:

`__config__.py`

These files are used as configuration. And they have unassigned python dictionary, like this:

```
{
  'name': 'Hello',
  'version': '0.4.1'
}
```

So what I need to do, is write to all those `__config__.py` files new version (for example `'version': '1.0.0'`).

**Update**

To be more specific, given that there is a python file with a content like this:

```
# Some important comment
# Some other important comment
{
'name': 'Hello',
'version': '0.4.1'
}
# Some yet another important comment
```

Now running some python script, it should write into python file modifying given dictionary and after writing, output should be like this:

```
# Some important comment
# Some other important comment
{
'name': 'Hello',
'version': '1.0.0'
}
# Some yet another important comment
```

So in other words, write should only modify `version` key value, and everything else should be kept like it was before writing.

Comment: since the content is a dictionary, maybe you could turn it into a json and do `json.dump()`?

Comment: Well you can [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) python literals, which your file contains. Writing back in pretty format is another thing though. Maybe [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) could help.

Comment: Perhaps this could be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768634/parse-a-py-file-read-the-ast-modify-it-then-write-back-the-modified-source-c

Comment: If its only `dict`s like your example, you could use `json` for that, it has arguments to control indentation etc. Also, you example is missing a `,`

Comment: @C14L sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: Is this question still too broad? So can I get an asnwer how can I narrow it down? Cause I edited the question, but it is still on hold.

Comment: This is in my opinion *way* too broad. However, since the `__config__.py` is Python code, why wouldn't you just have *code* there that reads the version from elsewhere.

Comment: How come it is too broad? I gave specific case. If such narrow case is too broad, then I dont what is not then. Well framework uses it like that, so I don't want to manually bump version for every module I have (and there are hundreds of em).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and what do you mean by having version elsewhere? Whats the point of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with solution. It is not very clean, but it works. If someone has a better answer, please write it.

```
content = ''
file = '__config__.py'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(content):
        # Could use regex too here
        if "'version'" in line or '"version"' in line:
            key, val = line.split(':')
            val = val.replace("'", '').replace(',', '')
            version_digits = val.split('.')
            major_version = float(version_digits[0])
            if major_version < 1:
                # compensate for actual 'version' substring
                key_end_index = line.index('version') + 8
                content[i] = line[:key_end_index] + ": '1.0.0',\n"
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    if content:
        f.writelines(content)
```

Comment: `sed` is a *nix utility that can be used for text transformations, but more popularly known for find and replace. http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html. If you just want to replace version numbers here is the command to do that 
`sed -e "s/'version': '0.4.1'/'version': '1.0.0'/g" test.cnf > new.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the config file, you can simply do sth like this:

```
import fileinput

lines = fileinput.input("__config__.py", inplace=True)
nameTag="\'name\'"
versionTag="\'version\'"
name=""
newVersion="\'1.0.0\'" 
for line in lines:
    if line[0] != "'":
        print(line)
    else:
        if line.startswith(nameTag):
            print(line)
            name=line[line.index(':')+1:line.index(',')]
        if line.startswith(versionTag):
            new_line = versionTag + ": " + newVersion
            print(new_line)
```

Notice that the print function here actually writes to a file.
for more details on how the print function do the writing for you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python)

I hope it helps.

Comment: `fileinput` is very dangerous to use with `inplace`, you're not using it in a context manager, thus potentially standard output is redirected to that file if an exception happens in the for loop. Additionally by `.strip()`ing lines you're also removing any indentation which will break the python code on those lines. Also, the slice is very dependent on the exact phrasing

Comment: well, I didn't actually notice stripping might break python indentation in the first place.thus, +1 for your comment !

Comment: Though, if the code contains *only* a dictionary and some comments, then there is no indentation to break.